# Best technique for memory allocation - reuse one gloabal memory or allocate many local buffers and let it be garbage collected

Tags: java

I am reading a bunch of byte messages from a file. 
I want to read each message into buffer, do a little parsing, and then store the messages a objects with field data.

In general, is it better to allocate one chunk of memory with a global reference and reuse it for each message I read or allocate local object a different chunk of memory for each message(this way it can be gargage collected since there are no global reference)?

Also, is there some reference somewhere that has list of good Java programming practices/design that might cover this and other desired techniques for building Java code? I have been coding Java for a long time but not sure if all my techniques are the most desirable.

Comment: use local, short-lived objects. objects that "die young" are good for GC.

Comment: I I have a lot messages I am parsing how is the garbage collecting performance vs. reusing the buffer

Comment: you need to profile your app with different strategies. I doubt you'll find big performance difference anyway.

Comment: 'Re-using the buffer'  really means 'implement my own garbage collection'. Don't try it. Let the GC do its work.

Comment: @bayou.io not if you need 1,000,000 x the same type of objects...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look into [Creational Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) in general.  This should give you a good platform to start with.

> Five well-known design patterns that are parts of creational patterns are the
>
> 1. **Abstract factory** pattern, which provides an interface for creating related or dependent objects without specifying the objects' concrete classes.
> 2. **Builder** pattern, which separates the construction of a complex object from its representation so that the same construction process can create different representations.
> 3. **Factory method** pattern, which allows a class to defer instantiation to subclasses.
>      =4. **Prototype** pattern, which specifies the kind of object to create using a prototypical instance, and creates new objects by cloning this prototype.
> 4. **Singleton** pattern, which ensures that a class only has one instance, and provides a global point of access to it.

These Creational Patterns are routinely used in high-performance Java applications.  But there needs to be a lot more detail and testing to know which pattern would improve your personal performance.

**Separately**, and going much further than simply better managing your object life-cycles.  There are libraries such as [OpenHFT](https://github.com/OpenHFT/OpenHFT) ( High Frequency Trading ) which will even let you IPC into a shared memory segment.  **No**, that's not what you want, and I am assuming you're not counting microseconds.  But I think it illustrates that going off the GC is not as far-fetched as described.

But if I were you, I'd experiment with a suitable Creational Pattern to better manage my Object Lifecycles.

Answer (score 0):

If you need you use the object/variable globally, then go that way. If not, and the method is being called multiple times, you might as well just create a local variable. It depends on how you plan to use it.
It will use more memory if you make an individual variable for each, but it should be fine. If you want a variable for each line or whatever just store the objects in a List or Array

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that by means of an example, you need to process 1,000,000 Row of the same type and number of objects. I that case instead of creating and dropping those value objects, and creating and dropping the Row object itself then in that case you would want to create it once at the beginning, use setters to modify for each iteration, and gc only at the very end only once. In that case you would want to keep a one row cache. 
This is what `ResultSet` is doing.